# Make LI items to follow a link

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="card">
  <ul>
    <li>Some text</li>
    <li>
      <div class="file">
        <a href="http://www.google.com">Link</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want all LI items to be click able if there is an anchor inside div.file.

The link to be followed should be the one in the anchor ...  I tried the following:

```
$(".card li .file:has(a)").click(function () {
  window.location = $("a:first", this).attr("href");
});
```

This is not working. Could, someone, help me out?

I have a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/Epvht) example.

**UPDATE**

I tried to do this only with CSS and HTML as suggested.
My problem is that the LI's might not have the same height.
I would like the click able area to be the same.

And I can't define height as "200px" or something like this because I do not want to have a bottom margin in case the content does not fill the entire space inside the DIV.

I created the following example:
http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/kxKrd

See the not click able part under the second LI item.

Comment: You shouldn't be using JavaScript for this. Make the `<a>` `display:block`, and make it the size you're after. See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/luEpf

Comment: Your code works as it should. The problem I assume here is that your code doesn't do what you think it should. If your goal is to make a link clickable and send the user somewhere then just the link is fine. It'll redirect for you. As @meager pointed out, no javascript necessary.

Comment: Adding to what @meagar rightfully said already – `a` can contain most block level elements in HTML5, so even if you want to have headlines and paragraphs within that list item, `li > a > …` is the structure you should use.

Comment: for an `<a>` to fill an `<li>` I typically make it's display as `inline-block` mess with it's `line-height` to fill the `<li>`.  Also make sure there is no padding or margin on the `<a>` and no padding on the `<li>`

Comment: @fnostro I did that but I keep having a problem ... Please, check the update on my post.

Comment: well it seems that making the a tags as block covers your clickable area for the whole LI - so what it actually seems you need is an `autoheight()` function that sets all the li's to the same height: [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qGxzB)

Answer (score 1):

Better:

```
li a, .file {
  height: 100%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pFwIj

Comment: Yes, I know ... But I need ALL li's to be click able. Not only the one that contains the anchor.

Comment: To what URL should the items without a link go?

Comment: But in your jQuery sample, you specifically look for `li`s with an `a` inside.

Comment: Yes, I know something is wrong with my JQuery ... What I tried is: check if .file contains a. If yes then make all LI items to have that link ... Or even maybe the UL

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the way .has() works.

Try this:

```
  $(".card li").has('.file a').click(function () {
    document.location.href = $("a:first", this).attr("href");
  });
```

NOTE:  Does not work in the CodePen for some reason, but works if you do `window.open()` instead of `document.location.href =`

Comment: I need all LI items to be clickable ... not only that one.

Comment: Ok ... what if there are more than one <div class="file"><a ....></a></div> ?  I must admit I'm not sure what functionality you are after here.

Comment: I just added an update ... Basically I have one URL which I need to follow whatever region you click on the LI items

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$(".card li").click(function() {
    var a = $(this).find("div.file a").first();
    if(a) {
       location.href = a.attr("href");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.

I think the problem lies in your example URL. Google blocks itself from being put in an iframe (like the one in the codepen example). You can see the errors if you open the browser console.
Try to use a normal URL for testing in codepen.

Also, the recommendation is to use `window.location.href = '';`

Answer (score 0):

Since the `a` is not necessarily related to the `li`, you shouldn't put it in the selector. Just bind the click function to the `li`, and get the `a` when they click on it.

```
$(".card li").click(function() {
    var link = $(".file a");
    if (link.count) {
        window.location = link.attr("href");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are triggering it when the div.file is pressed, which does not fill the li.  Wrap a :has() around the .file:has(a)

Try this:

```
$(".card li:has(.file:has(a))").click(function () {
  window.location = $("a:first", this).attr("href");
});
```